# CakePHP model belongs to any other model

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I am not sure what is the correct title. Here is my problem:

There are several models such as:
**Company 

Person (not same as the Users)

User

etc.**

Some of them needs to have one or more files attached to them.

So I have created an **UploadedFile** model. How to link this to any of the above models?
Sometimes the **UploadedFile** belongs to a **Company**.
Sometimes the **UploadedFile** belongs to **Person**

If an **UploadedFile** belongs to a **Company**, then it doesn't belong to others like **Person**.

All **UploadedFile** belongs to **User** (because they upload them and I need to track who uploaded it)

Does HABTM works here? Any other better ways?

Thank you very much for help.

Best regards,
Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the UploadedFile belog to all three (User, Company and Person):

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array('className' => 'User','foreignKey' => 'user_id'),
    'Company' => array('className' => 'Company','foreignKey' => 'company_id'),
    'Person' => array('className' => 'Person','foreignKey' => 'person_id'));
```

Since it always belong to a User, the user_id will always have a value.

Then you will check whether the company_id is set or the person_id is set and determine to which of them the file belongs. I have an application that works just like this. It is a bit painstaking, but I could not find any other solution

Another good idea will be to try and combine Person and Company in a single table, and just have a flag to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the quick reply. Sounds like a good idea. I will try that. I think this can also be used for another similar issue I have: Every company can have many shareholders, but the shareholder can be another company or a person.